# C# stream serialized classes across bluetooth or other similar network protocols

Tags: c#, networking

I am developing a windows phone 8 and windows 8 game and I need to make the game multiplayer over bluetooth or wireless.

So I am wondering if I can just serialize message classes and send them across the network.

I estimate quite some messages, more than 100 per second but they should be pretty small, less than 256 bytes.

Can I run into problems? What happens if there are too many messages sent over the network? Doesn't latencies interfere here?

Comment: At 256 bytes per message, sending a hundred of them per _second_ will be a huge load on the network of your users. 256 * 100 * 60 = 1,536,000 bytes per minute, or roughly 1.5 MB. Playing that game for a couple of hours will quickly deplete most user's data plan limit.

Comment: @JohnWillemse he did say over bluetooth or wireless, not carrier network

Comment: @Alecu Can you explain me how to do the multiplayer game over bluetooth or wireless network???